# using print inside def having yield statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-block

I am trying to print inside a function.
The function is used for invoking a block.
But I don't see the print happening in the function definition.
Please shed a light on this. Basically I am not clear with the control flow.

```
def find_all 
   matching_items = [] 

   self.each do |item|

      if yield(item)
         puts "after yield" #print not happening
         matching_items << item
      end
   end

   matching_items

end

p ['a', 'b','c','c'].find_all { |item| 
  if item == 'a'
     true 
  end   
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to `re-open` the class `Array` then, this is how you can do it

```
class Array
  def find_all(matching_items = [])
    self.each do |item|
      if yield(item)
        puts "after yield" #print not happening
        matching_items << item
      end
    end
    matching_items
  end
end

p ['a', 'b', 'c', 'c'].find_all { |item|
    if item == 'a'
      true
    end
  }
```

Output

```
after yield
["a"]
```

Answer (score 3):

If your code is exactly as written, you are defining and independent method `find_all` defined on `main`. When you type `[1,2,3,4].find_all`, you are calling the `find_all` method on `Array`, which is defined in the [Enumerable](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-find_all) method. So you are not calling your method at all.

What you are probably trying to do is

```
class Array
  def find_all
    ...
  end
end
```

This way, [1,2,3,4].find_all will call this method.

However, note that this is probably a bad idea: you're overriding a core method that in a class that isn't yours, so that could have consequences in other code that you are not able to anticipate if any other code uses the find_all method.

What you might try instead is to define a method that takes the array in as an argument. You might move this to a module, but for now:

```
def find_all(array)
  matching_items = [] 

   array.each do |item|

      if yield(item)
         puts "after yield" #print not happening
         matching_items << item
      end
   end

   matching_items

end
```

Of course, this is basically what `Enumerable#find_all` already does, but less efficiently: so perhaps this is just an academic exercise, in which case, great!, but otherwise, why not just use the existing method?

Comment: Great thanks for the clarification. I was coding just for my understanding. Using Enumerable would suffice